# Can not open EXE interactively while running PowerShell remotely using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, process, notepad, start-process

I am trying to execute PowerShell command on remote machine using C# code.
This command should launch notepad in the remote computer.
I am facing two issues:

1. While executing code, I can see process of notepad in Task Manager as running but I can't see window of notepad.
2. While closing runspace in the code, the notepad also gets closed.

I used reference from [here](https://medium.com/quick-code/execute-powershell-script-in-remote-machine-using-c-38cef87b796a) to write code.

```
 public PowerShellOutput RunRemotePowerShell(string computerName, string script)
 {
     AppConfig config = new AppConfig();
     PSCredential creds = CreateCredential(config.UserName, config.Password);
     Runspace runspace = GetRunSpace(computerName, creds);

     try
     {
         runspace.Open();

         using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell ps = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
         {
             ps.Runspace = runspace;
             ps.AddScript(script);

             string results = PropOutput(ps.Invoke());  
             
             var errors = ps.Streams.Error;

             // in case of no error, errors will be empty.
             StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();
             if (errors != null)
             {
                 foreach (var error in errors)
                 {
                     sbError.AppendLine(error.ToString());
                 }
             }

             string strError = sbError.ToString();
             PowerShellOutput objPSOutput = new PowerShellOutput();
             objPSOutput.PowerShellResult = results;    
             objPSOutput.PowerShellError = strError;

             return objPSOutput;

         }
     }

     //catch (PSRemotingTransportException ex)
     //{
     //    throw;
     //}

     catch
     {
         throw;
     }
     finally
     {
         if (runspace != null)
         {
             runspace.Close();
         }
     }
 }

 static void ExecuteExamples(string Script)
 {
Script = "Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe"     
Console.WriteLine(Script);
     PowerShellHelper objRP = new PowerShellHelper();
     PowerShellOutput objPSOutput = new PowerShellOutput();
     objPSOutput = objRP.RunRemotePowerShell("RemoteComputerName", Script);
     Console.WriteLine(objPSOutput.PowerShellResult);
     Console.WriteLine(objPSOutput.PowerShellError);
     //Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Comment: You can't launch an executable on a remote computer and have it show visibly on the remote computer.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart,  Thank you for the reply. Probably I will check and clarify the requirement then.

Comment: Unless you do some really wacky things involving sessions and window stations. It's not normally possible.